# Custom object input for CXF-JaxRS WebClient

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, webservice-client

I am pretty new to RESTful, and trying to create a sample services to achieve POST on void methods. I am able to test the method for String class but getting Exception while testing with custom object.

**ServiceClass:**

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/sayHello")
public void sayHello(Person person) {
    System.out.println("Hello there, " + person.getName());         
}

@Override
@POST
@Path("/sayHi")
public void sayHi(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hey there, " + name);       
}
```

**Test Clients:**

```
public void testSayHelloRest() throws Exception { 
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/ServicesTutorial/sampleService/sayHello");
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("My Name");           
    client.post(p);
   }

public void testSayHi() throws Exception {    
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/ServicesTutorial/sampleService/sayHi");  
    client.post("My Name"); 
}
```

Second test with simple String input passes, but the first test fails with below Exception

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: .No message body writer has been found for class : class com.wk.services.data.Person, ContentType : application/xml.
```

**Person class**

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate your Person class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Person {
    private String name;

    @XmlElement (name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. Could you please also explain what these annotations do?

Comment: @TeeGee Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html